# CKEditor use block style to inline

Tags: javascript, ckeditor, wysiwyg

I want to use block style to inline. When I click style button it change whole block of paragraph. My custom style button just doing h3. How can I do this?

Example screenshot;

First selecting text want to style.

[image: example]

After pressing cusstom style, but whole paragraph beign h3.

[image]

I want to do this;

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You will have to write a custom plugin. The CKEditor developers have stated several times that they don't like what you want to do and so they refuse to support it.

Comment: I understand their hesitation but is that hard; `<p>Lorem ipsum, test example</p>` to `<p>Lorem ipsum,</p><h3>test</h3><p>example</p>` Thats why I want to do in background.

Comment: I think that long ago I used to patch their code with these kind of fixes, but it's tiring trying to keep a lot of improvements and specially since they moved to github I haven't been able to keep a local set of changes and then easily update the rest of the code.

Comment: @musa Did you get this to work in any way? I also prefer your suggested behaviour over changing the whole block to the same style. That would be legit if there is no text selection. But if the user selects a piece of text, he clearly states that he only want to change the style of that specific selection.

Comment: @AdrianRosca unfortunately no.